# rake is broken after setting up capistrano and deprec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

Problem solved.

Deprec is not related to the application. Its function is to prepare the server to accept the application.  Removing deprec from my gemfile solved this problem.

I can't answer my own question within 8 hours, so I'm putting it here.

---

I have recently setup capistrano and deprec for my Rails 3 app, but now Rake no longer works.

I guess the problem is coming from deprec, but I'm not sure why deprec is involved with a Rake task.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jon

```
jon@prm01:~/id$ rake --trace 

(in /home/jon/id) rake aborted! Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe

/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.6.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/deprec-2.1.19/lib/deprec/recipes/canonical.rb:10 /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'  
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/deprec-2.1.19/lib/deprec/recipes_minus_rails.rb:5 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/deprec-2.1.19/lib/deprec/recipes.rb:6     
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/deprec-2.1.19/lib/deprec.rb:7 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'    
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require' 
/home/jon/id/config/application.rb:7 
/home/jon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require' 
/home/jon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require' 
/home/jon/id/Rakefile:4 /home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19:in `load' 
/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19
```

Here are the relevant files:

Rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

Id::Application.load_tasks
```

Application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module Id
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave', :git => 'https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.git' 
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'face'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'deprec'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprec is not related to the application. Its function is to prepare the server to accept the application. Removing deprec from my gemfile solved this problem.

*I am adding this, just to close out the question*